# Projection of vector onto multiple vectors

Tags: vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

im quite stuck at this one problem
Ive been given 3 vectors
$v0 = [1,-1,1,-1]$
$v1 = [1,1,1,1]$
$v2 = [2,0,-2,0]$
I am to "Calculate the projection px of vector $x = [3,2,1,0]$, onto $v0,v1,v2.$
I found a formula saying that the projection of vector v onto vector u could be found by:
$Pu \ for \ P=\frac{1}{||v||^2}vv^T$
However calculating the projection like that, gives me the wrong result. Can somebody point me into the right direction?

Comment: You might find a helpful approach to calculating vector projection here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571072/gram-schimidt-processtrying-to-understand-the-projection-operator/3571120#3571120.  I hope this helps.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1232189/265466 and many other related questions.

Comment: You say that you “found” a formula somewhere. Wasn’t orthogonal projection covered in the course material that you’re supposed to have studied before tackling the problem set?

Comment: Found in the textboox covering the subject. I found out my way was correct however, i was just doing matrix multiplication wrong in python.