# Distance from a point to a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Vectors ${\bf a,b,c,p}\in\mathbb{R}^{5}$ are given.
I want to know the distance $d$ from the point ${\bf p}$ to subspace $S=\mathrm{Span}\{{\bf a,b,c}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{5}$.

If the given vectors ${\bf a,b,c}$ are not orthogonal, how can we know the distance $d$?
As a first step, do we have to use Gram–Schmidt orthonormalization?

**Edit**:

In Wikipedia, I found a formula $P_A=A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T$. Can we use it to get the projected point $\hat{\bf p}$?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Yes, use Gram Schmidt.

Comment: Try to work out $\widehat{\mathbf{p}}:= \mathrm{proj}_{S}{\mathbf{p}}$ (the projection of $\mathbf{p}$ onto $S$). Then (by Pythagoras) $d = \sqrt{\left\|\mathbf{p}\right\|^2 - \left\|\widehat{\mathbf{p}}\right\|^2}$. (You can see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232189/question-about-projecting-vector-onto-subspace for an example of how to work out projections.)

Comment: Thank you. In Wikipedia, I found a formula $P_A=A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T$. Can we use it to get $\hat{\bf p}$?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Yes, you could use that. The matrix $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ is the matrix for projection onto the column space of $A$. So in your case, $A = \left[\mathbf{a}\mid \mathbf{b}\mid\mathbf{c}\right]\in \Bbb{R}^{5\times 3}$, the column space of $A$ is $S$, and $\widehat{\mathbf{p}} = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\mathbf{p}$. By the way, another way to get the same answer is to solve the linear system $A^T A \mathbf{x} = A^T\mathbf{p}$ for $\mathbf{x}\in \Bbb{R}^{3}$ (e.g. using Gaussian Elimination), and then $\widehat{\mathbf{p}}$ will be equal to $A\mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 3):

You want to compute $x \in S$ that minimizes $Q(x)=\|x-p\|^2$. Since $x = \alpha \vec a + \beta \vec b +\gamma \vec c$, you want to minimize
$$
Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) = \sum_{i=1}^5 (\alpha a_i + \beta b_i+\gamma c_i -p_i)^2.
$$

The minimizer is the only stationary point of $Q$ (you compute it solving a $3 \times 3$ linear system). Due to convexity, this is a global minimum. This is a typical least squares problem.